# Unicorn, RVM and Mac OS X Leopard

Tags: macos, rvm, osx-leopard, unicorn

I am trying to set up a small web server on my old mac mini G4 at home using the technologies mentioned in the title. I have learned that to serve anything on port 80, the server has to be started with sudo. Since I am using [RVM](https://rvm.io) to manage my Ruby Gems, I use rvmsudo to start the server.

I have created a user for running the server, and I can start the server by logging in via SSH and typing 'rvmsudo unicorn -p 80'. But of course when I close the connection the process is terminated, so this is obviously not the way to go.

What is the 'right' way to set up a server on Mac OS Leopard? Keeping in mind that I would like to keep using RVM to manage my gems. I would also like the server to start running automatically when the computer is booted.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the tool GNU screen 
http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/
and detach the screen, so the processes will continue running.

alternatively, you could try if this command does the trick:

```
rvmsudo unicorn -p 80
```